# Understanding Classes: Compose a Triangle from extending 3 points?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, composition

**Question:**
How can I take a Triangle Class extend Point(supers(?)) and compose an object that looks like this:

```
//  "name":"Thomas The Triangle",
//  "points": [
//     {age: "2015-05-28T06:23:26.160Z", x: 1, y: 1 }, 
//     {age: "2015-05-28T06:23:26.161Z", x: 0, y: 3 },
//     {age: "2015-05-28T06:23:26.164Z", x: 2, y: 3 }
//  ]
```

JS:

```
class Point {
  constructor(x, y){
    this.name = "Point"
    this.age = new Date();
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}



class Triangle extends Point{
  constructor(coords, name) {

    super(coords[0][0], coords[0][1]); //this line is best I could do but not correct
    this.name = name
  }


}
let t1 = new Triangle([[1,1],[0,3],[2,3]], 'Thomas The Triangle')
console.log(t1);
```

**

### [Live code for ES6](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=%2F**%0A%20*%20Classes%20and%20Inheritance%0A%20*%20Code%20Example%20from%20http%3A%2F%2Fwww.es6fiddle.net%2F%0A%20*%2F%0Aclass%20Point%20%7B%0A%20%20constructor(x%2C%20y)%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.name%20%3D%20%22Point%22%0A%20%20%20%20this.age%20%3D%20new%20Date()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20this.x%20%3D%20x%3B%0A%20%20%20%20this.y%20%3D%20y%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%0Aclass%20Triangle%20extends%20Point%7B%0A%20%20constructor(coords%2C%20name)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20super(coords%5B0%5D%5B0%5D%2C%20coords%5B0%5D%5B1%5D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20this.name%20%3D%20name%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%0A%7D%0Alet%20t1%20%3D%20new%20Triangle(%5B%5B1%2C1%5D%2C%5B0%2C3%5D%2C%5B2%2C3%5D%5D%2C%20'thomas')%0Aconsole.log(t1)%3B%0A%0A%20%0A)

**

Comment: Use inheritance carefully. Inheritance usually describes an **is-a** relationship. *Is* a triangle *a* point? I doubt it. *Is* a triangle *a* polygon? Yes. A triangle may *consist* of points, which indicates that you should use composition here.

Comment: I'm removing the `ecmascript-6` tag since this doesn't seem to be about ES6 specifically but rather about designing a specific class system conceptually.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't look like `Triangle` needs to extend `Point`. It rather compose multiple Point objects into array of points. Something like this:

```
class Triangle {
  constructor(coords, name) {
    this.points = coords.map((point) => {
        return new Point(...point);                        
    });
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

Comment: Extending would mean that Triangle _is_ a point, which doesn't sound correct. This answer is correct because a triangle _has_ points.